# Can not load mysql_num_rows on CodeIgniter 3.1.0

Tags: php, codeigniter, mysqli, codeigniter-3

Before I use CodeIgniter 2.2.0 on my project with php5.5 and it went well , but after I upgrade installed ubuntu 16.04 php7.0 turns out , there are many problems there my project I finally upgraded my CodeIgniter to version 3.1.0 . after I edit php.ini finally solved yet another problem I could not display mysql_num_rows.

This myscript on Views

```
<div class="pull-right number"> 
<?php 
    $date = date("Ymd");
    echo mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tbcounter WHERE date='$date' GROUP BY ip"));              
?>
</div>
```

Alert error

> An uncaught Exception was encountered
>
> Type: Error
>
> Message: Call to undefined function mysql_num_rows()
>
> Filename: /var/www/html/inventory_3/application/views/user/monitoring.php
>
> Line Number: 86

Comment: msql extention is now deprecated...

Comment: Try with mysqli_num_rows()

Comment: thanks @RajkumarR I've tried to replace with `mysqli_num_rows `, but the error `Call to undefined function mysql_query ( )`

Answer (score 0):

In codeigniter u should do like

```
$this->db->query('Your Query Here')->num_rows();
```

Comment: thanks @AbuHuraira Lakdawala do not run , I tried to show in views to easily identify ip on date